# How many times can you use the Google Geocoding API for free?

Tags: python, geocoding

I’m having some problems using the google geocode API. I don't know if the paying system has changed recently but I can only use the `geocode.geolocation` statement once a day.

When I use a `gmap.geocode` function using my api key, I get the correct return value but after that, I get a `Timeout` error. Is this something that can be changed in my local settings or is the geocode API actually restricted to one request a day?  Using the following code,

```
import googlemaps
key='**********************'
gmap=googlemaps.Client(key=key)
print(gmap.geocode('서울중부경찰서',language='ko'))
```

I get an error like

```
raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()
```

Timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out google's price plans changed and the geocoding api is still provided free until a quite amount of requests, but you have to register a payment method(credit card) to use the api.